# nuxt universal mode, console.log to output file name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Is there a way to output console.log in "universal" mode so that the filename of the console.log shows? Right now it only shows vendor.app

i.e.

```
hi vendors.app.js:12757
```